# .m file become read only when debugging in matlab-mode

Tags: gud, matlab

Is it possible to add a hook or set a configuration variable such that the `.m` file I am debugging remains in edit mode when debugging starts. I don't want to switch out of read-only mode to interactively debug and code.

It seems this behavior is relatively new since older versions did not enforce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same question. After reading through the matlab-shell-gud.el and playing around with code, I got the following to work:

```lisp
    (add-hook 'matlab-shell-prompt-appears-hook
              (lambda ()
                (global-matlab-shell-gud-minor-mode 0)))
```

Now it starts in edit mode and `C-x C-q` switches into debug mode.

Comment: I reindented your code. You likely pasted code that used TAB chars for indenting. Use `M-x untabify` to replace TABs with spaces before pasting here, or readjust after pasting.